# Wordpress returning 0 on ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I having problems with Wordpress always returning 0 on this ajax call. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Ajax:

```
$j.ajax({  
       type: 'POST',  
       url: 'http://localhost/all-in-one/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
      data: {  
         action: 'header_galley_ajax',
         id: '1'
       },  
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
        alert (data); 
       },  
     error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
         alert('error:'+errorThrown);  
     }  
     });
```

functions.php:

```
function header_galley_ajax () {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo "ajax fired:".$id;
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ header_galley_ajax', 'header_galley_ajax' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ header_galley_ajax', 'header_galley_ajax' );
```

Comment: just noticed the white space in the add_actions. solved

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove spaces in 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ header_galley_ajax' and 'wp_ajax_ header_galley_ajax':

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_header_galley_ajax', 'header_galley_ajax' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_header_galley_ajax', 'header_galley_ajax' );
```